# Extract all content nodes

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, xmlnode

I extract a Content node from [this XML.](http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?appid=dj0yJmk9TU1hbThtN0IwRjYzJmQ9WVdrOVMzWjVNR05GTXpBbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1kYg--YahooDemo&query=cars)

I use this code for extract the Content node, but i need extract all content node.

How can i do?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?appid=dj0yJmk9TU1hbThtN0IwRjYzJmQ9WVdrOVMzWjVNR05GTXpBbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD1kYg--YahooDemo&query=cars"), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);            
    }

    private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result, LoadOptions.None);
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                XNamespace ns = "urn:yahoo:answers";
                var Content = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Content").FirstOrDefault();
                MessageBox.Show(Content.Value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }                   
    }
```

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer do not forget to mark it as accepted. This is not the first time you ignore it.

Comment: i can't mark the answer because i haven't 15 reputation :(

Comment: i've read it but it dosen't resolve the problem!

Comment: You can't upvote untill you have 15 of reputation. But you can and you should accept answers. Otherwise why should people help you?

Comment: Ok sorry, i will not forget it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var contents = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Content");

 foreach(var content in contents){
    MessageBox.Show(content.Value);
  }
```